# How to restrict the narrator from reading the default content when the Button is focused

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have created a custom control using the UI.Xaml.Control.Button and need to provide Accessibility support for the same. I need to set a custom content that reports to the UI Automation framework when the Button is on focus. But, the default content "Double Tap to activate" is automatically read by the narrator because of built-in Button behavior. How to restrict the default content?

Comment: What's the custom content? Could you give me a simple code sample?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT We can give custom content in source-level using SetValue() method like the below code.                 this.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "Double tap to clear the text");

Answer (score 0):

> We can give custom content in source-level using SetValue() method like the below code. this.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "Double tap to clear the text");

By my test, you need to call the `SetValue()` method of the Button, instead of the page. Then, the narrator will read the updated content.

```
<Button x:Name="btn" AutomationProperties.Name="Double Tap to activate" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btn.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "Double tap to clear the text");
}
```